# How to split/parse and write the contents of text file (single list) into multiple lists using Python 3?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, file

Suppose I read a file (.txt file) in Python 3. Next, I need to parse the contents of single list, into multiple lists with respect to the white spaces and `\n` sentence breakers of the original file.

What I need is to write and save the new file containing the list of lists separately.

After this operation I should have 2 files in the directory, one containing the `entire text in a single list` and the other `containing only the list of lists`.

I have tried but not yet succeeded, any help is appreciated.

The code at which I am strucking is as follows.

```
import nltk, re
import string
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer, sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg, stopwords
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

def remove_punctuation(from_text):
    table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
    stripped = [w.translate(table) for w in from_text]
    return stripped

def preprocessing():
    with open("I:\\(2018 - 2019)\\College Desktop\\Pen Drive 8 GB\\PDF\\Code\\Books Handbooks\\Books Handbooks Text\\b1.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
         tokens_sentences = sent_tokenize(f.read())
         tokens = [[word.lower() for word in line.split()] for line in tokens_sentences]
         global stripped_tokens
         stripped_tokens = [remove_punctuation(i) for i in tokens]
         sw = (stopwords.words('english'))
    filter_set = [[token for token in sentence if (token.lower() not in sw and token.isalnum() and token.isalpha() and re.findall(r"[^_ .'\"-[A-Za-z]]+", token))] for sentence in stripped_tokens]
    lemma = WordNetLemmatizer()
    lem = []
    for w in filter_set:
        lem.append([wi for wi in map(lemma.lemmatize, w)])
    return lem
result = preprocessing()
with open('I:\\(2018 - 2019)\\College Desktop\\Pen Drive 8 GB\\PDF\\Code\\Books Handbooks\\Books Handbooks Text\\b1_list.txt', "w", encoding="utf-8")  as f1:
    for e in result[:3]:  
        f1.write(str(e))
preprocessing()
```

I am frustrated, because the program executes correctly. No error but output is not as desired. For example, In the above code I wish to write first 3 sentences in the new file.

But when I open the new file, it shows me 3 empty list, somewhat like [][][]. Why is it so?

Comment: It would help us to distil the problem down to it's bare parts. Have you tried inserting print statements in the program to track your variables?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. What the need of print statements. This is because the program is correct and it generates a new file. However, the generated file is empty, I am curious to know this reason!

Comment: This is not minimal nor verifiable. Clearly, the program isn't correct, as it does not do what you want. We have no idea what your input file is, so we can't replicate it.

Comment: Okay Thank You. By the way, The file is a text file containing only text data and text file is plaintext and simple. Thank you for the response. I have also provided the minimal working example.